# Duplicating Jenkins job to some other jenkins

Tags: jenkins

I have this task to Create some jobs on Jenkins that runs on a server. Is there any way that could duplicate all the jobs which I created on the Jenkins which ran on my local machine to the Jenkins which runs on a server.

what Would happen if I replace my Jenkins's configure? XML file with someone else's Jenkins Configure.XML

Answer (score 0):

Following link from Jenkins Wiki should be helpful.

[Administering Jenkins](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Administering+Jenkins#AdministeringJenkins-Moving%2Fcopying%2Frenamingjobs)

Answer (score 0):

Did this with the Jenkins job importer plugin :)